# Select parent with child angular 4 options array inside array

Tags: angular

I have a web service get array of countries and inside each country services so i want to do select option make user able to select country or service

I want to do like this

[image]

```
<select [(ngModel)]="countries"  (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"  >
      <option *ngFor="let c of countries" [ngValue]="c">{{c.nom}} </option>
            <option *ngFor="let service of services" [ngValue]="service"> &nbsp; {{service.nom}} </option>
</select>
```

from the web service i get like this [countries] and in console.log when i click in countries i get list of countries and inside list of services

The data structure look like this [image]

with this code i get countries and last services :(, i think i need two for because array inside array but i don't know how to do it, so anyone can help me to resolve this issue and thanks

Comment: You should use `optgroup` to achieve this, ie: `<optgroup *ngFor="let c of countries" [ngValue]="c">{{c.nom}}>... <options *ngFor...>... </optgroup>`... Btw, how is your data structure? I'm asking because makes more sense if your *services* are groupped by *countries*.. however it doesn't seem to.

Comment: thanks @developer033 you help to have idea, but can answer to this question or you want  data structure ?

Comment: Can you include your data structure first?

Comment: @developer033 ok

Comment: I just posted an answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you want you should use [**optgroup**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup).

**Ex:**

```
<optgroup *ngFor="let obj of arr" [label]="obj.PROP">
  <option *ngFor="let nestedObj of obj.nestedArray">{{nestedObj.PROP}}</option>
</optgroup>
```

In your case, it would be as follows:

```
<optgroup *ngFor="let c of countries" [label]="c.nom">
  <option *ngFor="let service of c.services" [ngValue]="service">{{service.nom}}</option>
</optgroup>
```

[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/rJ3czfoHKGYsE5aaUOav?p=info)

Answer (score -1):

Try to map your country and services to a new array:

```
this.countryServices = [];

let data = [
  {country: 'Spain', services: ['spainSservice1', 'spainService2']},
  {country: 'Canada', services: ['canadaservice1', 'canadaservice2']},
];

data.map(country => {
  this.countryServices.push(country.country);
  country.services.map(service => {
    this.countryServices.push(service);
  })
});
```

And then in your template this:

```
<select>
  <option *ngFor="let cs of countryServices" [ngValue]="cs">{{cs}}</option>
</select>
```

I hope this helps you.